# SSRS 2016 - Tablix in subgroup fails upon deployment

Tags: sql-server-2016, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2016, reporting-services-2016

SQL Server 2016, SSRS: I have an expandable group that works correctly in Report Builder or Visual Studio SSDT, but does not display when run on the server.

My charter was to create a report that didn't rely on pop-ups or new windows to display detail data. I've managed to embed that detail data below each order. A single dataset feeds the entire report. The user views a list of orders and can click an expand control on a given order to see the detail.

There are three groups in the report: District, Date and Order. Each group is expandable. At the bottom most 'Order" level several rows are displayed, including three that have tablixes embedded in them.

Problem: The order number and expand control [+] work fine in development but are not visible when running on the server.

This image shows the report in Development mode in VS 2017. Note the sections starting with 'Order Type' and 'Low Flow Test are Tablixes, each with a single header and a single row of data:

[image: Design view]

This second image shows the report in preview mode in VS 2017. It's displaying correctly with a single order expanded:

[image: Report in Preview Mode]

This third image shows the same report running on the server. Note the 'OrderNum' group cannot be expanded - the Order number field isn't even visible:

[image: Report running on server]

Both Visual Studio and Report Builder render this report as desired. When running in a browser this fails on IE, Chrome and Edge.

Either this is a bug or there's something I don't know about how this all works.

Comment: I can't say I've seen this behavior before, except when a field overruns (is wrapping). Have you tried to expand the Order column temporarily to say double its current width, just to at least rule this out?

Comment: Drat. No. I just tried it with high hopes, but the result is the same.

Comment: UPDATE: If I run the report, then save as Excel, the order numbers appear and the dropdowns work!

More food for thought.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure what to do. I might try adding a new column and step and step replicating your original bad column until it fails. Its definitely some rendering issue. Be interesting to inspect the web page too, see if it's even being sent to the browser.

Comment: I may have to. I'll post an update if I find anything definitive. <sigh>

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and got it resolved. It was because of the over-flow: hidden that was put on these tablix headers. Under alignment my vertical alignment was set to 'bottom'. After setting it to 'Default' it was fixed. I guess having alignment as bottom made the browser think it was over-flow text.